# View images transferred to Google Glass via USB

Tags: android, image, usb, google-glass, google-gdk

Does anyone know if it's possible to transfer JPEG images to Glass via USB, and then view the images on Glass?

I tried copying the images on my PC and pasting to both the "DCIM" and "Pictures" folder under Glass' "USB storage" folder, but that didn't seem to work. I could see the images inside those two folders on my PC after the transfer was done, however, I just couldn't view them in my Glass.

Comment: I found this Gallery For Glass (http://w9jds.github.io/Gallery4Glass/#download) glassware app. However, I am not sure if it supports what I am hoping to do, specifically, I am not sure what he meant by "sideloading" images (in the description).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This app allows you to browse all the media files in your DCIM/Camera directory http://html5webapp.blogspot.de/2014_04_01_archive.html

So download the zipped file, extract it, place the resulting `.apk` file in `<sdk>/platform-tools/`

Then on the command line (or terminal), go to the directory where the `[application.apk]` file is, and type the following commands while the Google glass is connected, and debug mode is on:

```
adb install [application.apk]
```

If you want to uninstall it later, type:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

This will list the packages installed on your glass, look for the `[package-name]` that describes the app you installed and type:

```
adb uninstall [package-name]
```

Now wear the glasses, tap while in the card that shows the time, you'll get a list of applications that includes: "Media Gallery", it should include your new files.

Comment: Nice. This looks like exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for recommending this app, as well as providing the installation steps. They are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible now via standard Glass UI.
You can write your own Gallery-like GDK app though.

**From technical standpoint:**

1. Cards in Glass Timeline are not simple pictures.
2. Seems like, Cards are populated via specific `ContentProvider` deep inside Glass. After you take a picture, another Card instance is created and inserted into Timeline. But this API is not available to anyone right now.
3. *Technically*, you can write your own Gallery-like GDK application, which would allow you to watch pictures available.

**From Glass/UX standpoint**

The idea of Timeline is that cards go to the past.
From [Glass Design](https://developers.google.com/glass/design/ui):

> Glass pushes older cards farther to the right where users rarely scroll and removes cards older than 7 days or when the 200 card limit is reached.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of, of course they won't make it simple for their users. On the side note, do you know if there's any third party glass apps that can do that? I don't have the time to learn and write my own gallery app.

Comment: I found this Gallery For Glass (http://w9jds.github.io/Gallery4Glass/#download) glassware app that seems to be the kind of application you mentioned. However, I am not sure if it supports what I am hoping to do, specifically, I am not sure what he meant by "sideloading" images (in the description).

Comment: `sideloading` in Glass's context usually means uploading various files to Glass: apps, images, etc. Seems like this glassware is for creating vignettes primarily. Nonetheless, try it! Seems like at least it will allow you to add a picture to Glass, as you did it before and add vignette to it.